# Why this logic function prints 7 in option A and not in B?

Tags: python

Why does option a) prints x, while on b) it doesn't? By the way, both operations should bring the result of b).

a)

```
x = 7

if x >3 & x<=6:
    print(x)
```

b)

```
x = 7

if x >3:
    if x<=6:
        print(x)
```

Comment: and is spelled `and` in Python (not `&` - which is the binary and operator).

Comment: `3 & x` is 3. Your first code is checking `x > 3` and `3 <= 6`.

Comment: @thebjorn probably OP's intention were actually to perform a logical  `and`. But the question is why the condition is true with & operator.

Answer (score 4):

The ampersand (`&`) character is a bitwise operator. From the [Python Wiki page on Bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

> x & y
>
> Does a "bitwise and". Each bit of the output is 1 if the corresponding bit of x AND of y is 1, otherwise it's 0.

If you evaluate your expression `x >3 & x<=6`, the result is:

```
x >3 & x<=6
7 > 3 <= 6
True <= 6
True
```

... which is why your code reaches the final condition and outputs `7`.

---

What you're looking for is the logical `and` token:

```
x = 7

if x >3 and x<=6:
    print(x)
```

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Updated to reflect this aspect of the question, thanks

Comment: `x >3 & x<=6` is not parsed as `1 & 1`, as `&` has a higher priority than `<`. See @khelwood's answer for the correct explanation.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Ah yes... seems I totally missed this point in my haste to answer! I've updated to reflect the correct logic - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This condition:

```
if x >3 & x<=6
```

is checking if `x > (3&x)` and `(3&x) <= 6`.

`x` is 7, so `3&x` is equal to 3. So both conditions are true.

---

In general, if you want to check if two conditions are both true, use `and`.

```
if x > 3 and x <= 6:
```

For what you want in this case, you can do it more concisely:

```
if 3 < x <= 6:
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer: `&` has higher priority than `<`, so `3&x` gets evaluated first, then the comparisons get chained.

Answer (score 1):

With the first, you are using the bitwise operator for and, instead of `and` which correctly would not print `x` in the case of 7.